# Why AND(&) operator used calculating final index in Hashmap why not modulo(%) operator i.e hashValue & ()

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I am trying to understand HashMap implementation. I found after calculating key hash value, final hash value is generated using AND operator (hashValue & (n-1)) where n is size of bucket.Could someone explain why modulo is not used which will also guarantee output range within bucket size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` runs faster, in exchange for working only for powers of two.  (Specifically, `x & (n - 1) == x % n` if `x` is nonnegative and `n` is a power of two.  `x & (n - 1)` also does what you want for a hash table -- even if `x` is negative, `x & (n - 1)` isn't -- unlike `x % n`.)

That's the complete and only reason.

Comment: It's also important to note that `%n` and `&(n-1)` are equivalent when n is a power of 2. It's not clear that OP understands this.